# Is 'a' representing 1 in "ch = input[c] - 'a' "?

Tags: c

I've been working with some basic coding challenges and I've come across this syntax "ch = input[c] - 'a'" a couple of times and I would like to understand it before moving on.

```
n = strlen(input);
for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
    ch = input[c] - 'a';
    no[ch]++;
}
```

Comment: It gives the ordinal position of the lower-case letter ranging from `0..25` (assuming they are consecutive, which in ASCII coding, they are).

Comment: `'a' - 'a'` = 0, `'z' - 'a'` = 25. (Characters are integer values in C: see how a..z are arranged numerically in an [(ASCII) character table](https://www.google.com/search?q=ascii+tablke) and note that A..Z are a separate range)

Comment: The code is counting the occurrences of the lower-case letters in `input[]`. It will break if there are any upper-case letters because there is no range checking.

Comment: This is very dangerous code if input is anything other than characters less than `a` in ASCII range.

Comment: There is an unstated (code comments would work well) and unguarded assumption that `'a'` has the lowest character code for the expected input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'a'=97` format is based on ASCII table
and when you want to use alphabets whit their  numbers, it will be useful.

This program wants to count number of each alphabet in your input
so it well increase the index of array which is the same of your alphabet index.

As we see `'a'` is `48` and for example for `'b'` , `ch=49-48=1`
so  in `index=1` you will see `cb[index]+=1`

Comment: actually, 'a' is ordinal 97, not ordinal 48.  ordinal 48 is 'A'

Answer (score 1):

```
ch = input[c] - 'a';
no[ch]++;
```

The array `no` keeps in the *i* <sup>th</sup> element the count of the *i* <sup>th</sup> lowercase letter from the string `input`.

However, if your input contains other characters than lowercase letters , your code may break.  On the other hand, it is supposed you allocated enough space in `no` for any letter.

Comment: if there was enough space in no[] for any letter, then it would be an error to adjust the value by: `- 'a'`